# Android Studio screen tearing on dual monitors

Tags: android, android-studio, ide, graphic, multiple-monitors

I recently installed Android Studio to learn more about app development. However, I'm seeing screen tearing to such an extent that the IDE is pretty much unusable. Demonstration in the photos below:

[Example showing a typical screen tear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2Ns1.jpg)

[Example showing NO tearing (same project, same editor view - captured by minimising the window, re-maximising it, then quickly taking the pic)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cM7ET.jpg)

For the avoidance of doubt, this screen tearing is **only** happening within Android Studio on my Windows 10 machine. No screen tearing happens within games, editors such as Notepad++, or suchlike.

Some of the things I've tried to pinpoint the issue:

- Changing my graphics card settings, back when I didn't know it was limited to Android Studio. I have a GeForce GTX 980, and various googling led me to tweaking VSync to adaptive and Triple Buffering to On in the hope it resolved the issue. I also tried changing my two identical monitors' refresh rate (connected via Display Port cables, Extended desktops) from 60hz to 59 and 50 to see if it might resolve it. No luck.
- Changing many of the Android Studio appearance settings e.g. turning window animations on or off, changing the tooltip MS delay timer, turning off file synchronization/file saving on frame activation and background saving entirely, etc.
- Even changing the Android Studio config e.g. -Xmx2048m instead of the default 750mb.

In terms of triggers, the issue is intermittent, but when it does start, it's there until I reboot my machine. In other words, it doesn't relate to my running a phone emulation or having a specific phone emulated, nor what other programs are running on my machine at the same time, nor if the phone "preview" screen is showing, nor if a gradle build is running in the background, etc.

Other interesting aspects that I've spotted are:

1. The screen tearing seems to be concentrated around where the mouse cursor or keyboard input is located, not randomly on the screen.
2. I think the issue is not occurring when my monitors are set to Duplicate their displays, rather than Extend. I'm not 100% sure on this yet though; I certainly haven't seen it in half hour experiment using the Duplicated monitors.

I'm now out of ideas, and ready to give up on Android Studio.

Although this feels more likely to be a hardware or graphics issue, because Android Studio is the first and only thing that I've experienced issues with, I was hoping someone else may have an answer about what else to try.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue as well on Android Studio 2.0. I fixed by disabling G-Sync on my Nvidia GTX980

Answer (score 0):

See Android Issue Tracker http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=189308 ("Screen garbled / messed up when repaint on 1.4").